# Repeat part of my sub

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'd like to run a part of my Sub, with a different keyword each time it's run. Currently I'm writing like this, but is there a shorter way I could be doing it?

I'm making a category for Direct Debits, ATM Cash Withdrawals, and Debit Card Purchases in Column D - Searching for D/D, C/L, and POS respectively in column B.

I'm changing the variables, but typing and running the same bit of code every time. I feel like there should be a way to say "Run that bit again, but with Searchterm and Searchresult changed!"

I'm sure someone more knowledgable than I could help. I'm already using a sub so can't insert another sub to run within it, or a function? And I'm already looping so I'm not sure how another loop would fit in?

What would you do? As you can probably guess I'm quite new to this, with only a little js knowledge in the past.

```
Sub OrganiseDefaultCategories()
    '
    ' OrganiseDefaultCategories Macro
    ' Categorise the Bank Statement Entries with Default inputs. Run this first.
    '

    Dim FoundRange As Range, FirstAddress As String, Searchterm As Variant, Searchresult As Variant

    Searchterm = "D/D"
    Searchresult = "Direct Debit"

        With Range("b:b")
      Set FoundRange = .Find(What:=Searchterm, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address
      Do
        FoundRange.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Searchresult

        Set FoundRange = .FindNext(FoundRange)
      Loop While Not FoundRange Is Nothing And FoundRange.Address <> FirstAddress

      Searchterm = "C/L"
    Searchresult = "ATM Cash Withdrawal"


      Set FoundRange = .Find(What:=Searchterm, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address
      Do
        FoundRange.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Searchresult

        Set FoundRange = .FindNext(FoundRange)
      Loop While Not FoundRange Is Nothing And FoundRange.Address <> FirstAddress

      Searchterm = "POS"
    Searchresult = "Debit Card Purchase"


      Set FoundRange = .Find(What:=Searchterm, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address
      Do
        FoundRange.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Searchresult

        Set FoundRange = .FindNext(FoundRange)
      Loop While Not FoundRange Is Nothing And FoundRange.Address <> FirstAddress

    End With


    End Sub
```

Comment: I would make searchTerm and searchResult optional arguments to the sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OrganiseDefaultCategories()
  '
  ' OrganiseDefaultCategories Macro
  ' Categorise the Bank Statement Entries with Default inputs. Run this first.
  '

  Dim SearchTerm As String
  Dim SearchResult As String

  SearchTerm = "D/D"
  SearchResult = "Direct Debit"
  Finder SearchTerm, SearchResult
  SearchTerm = "C/L"
  SearchResult = "ATM Cash Withdrawal"
  Finder SearchTerm, SearchResult
  SearchTerm = "POS"
  SearchResult = "Debit Card Purchase"
  Finder SearchTerm, SearchResult

End Sub

Sub Finder(ByVal SearchTerm As String, ByVal SearchResult As String)

  Dim FoundRange As Range
  Dim FirstAddress As String

  With Range("b:b")
    Set FoundRange = .Find(What:=SearchTerm, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
      FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address
      Do
        FoundRange.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = SearchResult
        Set FoundRange = .FindNext(FoundRange)
      Loop While Not FoundRange Is Nothing And FoundRange.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

I created a small procedure `Finder` that takes 2 parameters, `SearchTerm` and `SearchResult`, then set variables and call `Finder` for each pair.

I also declared those two as `String` instead of `Variant`. You really only want to use `Variant` when absolutely necessary (some functions require a `Variant`) because it can lead to hard to find errors, and it's slower to execute.

I also modified your code slightly when I extracted it into the `Finder` procedure to ensure that we check the result of the `.Find` to ensure we have something (i.e. `Not ... is Nothing`) *before* attempting to use it in any way. VBA does *not* do short circuit `IF` statements, so if you didn't find anything with `.Find`, you would have still received an error the way you originally had it written.

Congrats on using `.Find` instead of looping through all the rows making a comparison! `.Find` will be significantly faster.

Comment: Absolutely amazing answer - this is just what I was looking for! Great advice with the IF - that's a really good idea, and helps if I'm searching new account statements in the future!  I originally used string, as I had my variables set as input boxes! This lives on as another 'OrganiseCustomCategories' Sub - but took an age to create them all manually. this method of having 'default' values speeds up my accounting incredibly, and no longer needs to be a variant! Another good catch! I'm learning so much, thankyou :)

Comment: make sure you up vote any and all answers that helped you (click the up arrow next to them), and click the check mark of the one that you found _most_ helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the common code into a Sub, then call it:

```
Private Sub WhateverThisDoes(Searchterm As String, Searchresult As String)
    Set FoundRange = .Find(What:=Searchterm, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address
    Do
        FoundRange.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Searchresult

        Set FoundRange = .FindNext(FoundRange)
    Loop While Not FoundRange Is Nothing And FoundRange.Address <> FirstAddress
End Sub
```

From the calling procedure:

```
WhateverThisDoes "C/L", "ATM Cash Withdrawal"
WhateverThisDoes "POS", "Debit Card Purchase"
'...
```

Comment: Of course! Yes, this is exactly what I needed! It makes life so much easier to organise the list of variables too! Fantastic work. I re-wrote my script as needed to suit the problem, using yours as a template - this has also taught me how to solve this problem in the future too. Fantastic response, thank you so much! I didn't know you could add variables to the sub input - it's so obvious now!